# Arbitrage Opportunities in a Two-Zero Coupon Bond Market

Tags: arbitrage, asset-pricing, zero-coupon

**Question**:
Suppose we are in a market where there are only two zero coupon bonds, both with a face value of 100: the first one with a maturity of one year and a price of 90, and the second one with a maturity of two years and a price of 40.

I would like to know if this market is free of arbitrage opportunities. If not, why?
Additionally, if I were to purchase the two-year zero coupon bond, what would be the fair price after six months if I intended to resell it?

**My Attempt**:
I don't see how the market could allow for arbitrage opportunities since the maturities are different, and there is no way to start with an initial wealth of 0 and end up with wealth > 0 in the future. Concerning the second question, I do not understand how it is possible to price such a coupon after six months, given that the shortest maturity coupon is only one year.